# Using "moderately" correlated variables to select controls for a LASSO regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, lasso, regularization, regression-strategies

In medicine we often have a disease status as an outcome variable and a lot of independent variables in which we want to see if there is some connection. Traditionally, baseline characteristics such as age, gender and sometimes weight are used as control variables and then a multiple regression is performed once per independent variable to see if there is a correlation. Then some may proceed with stepwise regression and  run another multiple regression (although this is phasing out).

Often times the problem is we don't know what we need to control for as the human body can be incredibly deceptive and correlations exist sometimes in places we never suspected.

I thought perhaps regressing like we usually do and set alpha=0.2 or so for a "moderate" threshold in which we take those variables and then run them in a LASSO regression with all other variables of the study as controls, from which LASSO will select the best fits.

Is this a possible or terrible idea?

Comment: Are your goals inference or prediction? From what I’ve read LASSO should be avoided for inference.

Comment: I honestly can't tell the difference between the two...?

Comment: Also note that running several regression models testing each factor (age, gender, weight) individually is a bad way to “screen” factors for a relationship with the outcome. If confounding is present, failing to account for the confounders in the model will significantly overestimate or underestimate the effect by the independent variable (see omitted variable bias). Better to use some subject knowledge to identify strong confounders and then fit a single model with these confounders and see what the relationship is for each variable while accounting for confounding

Comment: We have no idea what affects this outcome so we have no subject knowledge to draw from.

Comment: See this paper https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/09332480.2019.1579578  for an explanation on prediction vs (causal) inference. If you're operating without any subject knowledge I'm not really sure how to proceed. I'm an informatics student and had the same question about learning important variables without subject matter knowledge. Unfortunately I haven't found any great solutions. I think you'll find lots of people saying it's a very hard problem and no great solution exists. Is there any biological data that would suggest potential factors?

Comment: "n which we want to see if there is some connection." is clearly inferential. Also, medicine is traditionally very consevative; so $p$-values are traditionally very important. @TomasBencomo has not explained why LASSO should be avoided for inference. Is it maybe a the lack of standard errors?